# Python (tornado) app in Azure webapp : Start up command

Tags: python, azure, tornado

We have a very basic app which serves a couple of APIs. It was deployed in Azure Webapp (linux) and was working fine with below startup command :

gunicorn -k tornado app:app --timeout 600

This weekend the app crashed with below error :

> 2021-06-01T11:55:55.725316108Z   File "/tmp/8d924f2d159cada/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/http1connection.py", line 273, in _read_message
> 2021-06-01T11:55:55.725320108Z     delegate.finish()
> 2021-06-01T11:55:55.725323408Z   File "/tmp/8d924f2d159cada/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/httpserver.py", line 280, in finish
> 2021-06-01T11:55:55.725349308Z     self.request_callback(self.request)
> 2021-06-01T11:55:55.725352908Z   File "/tmp/8d924f2d159cada/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/wsgi.py", line 113, in **call**
> 2021-06-01T11:55:55.725356508Z     app_response = self.wsgi_application(
> 2021-06-01T11:55:55.725359908Z TypeError: **call**() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

### Our app.py (It returns endpoints):

```
return tornado.web.Application(endpoints, debug=False)

logging.info('Got here') 


def main():
    app = make_app()
    return app

app = main()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("starting tornado server..........")
    app.listen(tornado.options.options.port)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

Tornado version 6.1
Python : 3.8

The logging info is to make sure that the app is initialised. This works perfectly in our local environment and was working until this weekend in Azure App service.

The error does say that it is calling tornado/wsgi and fails . On my troubleshooting so far we could find that tornado 6.1 doesn't use wsgi anymore. I am confused and can't find a fix.

I am doubting the startup command is causing all the issue. How can we fix the error?

Comment: Do you have a special use case for running Tornado on gunicorn? Because Tornado is meant to be run as a standalone server.

Comment: No we do not have any such requirement. We couldn't find a way to run tornado directly is Azure app service. Its just this startup command which works. Any suggestion to improve this please.

Comment: You can run the service using just by using `if __name__ == "__main__"` block.

Comment: @xyres : The app runs fine locally. Its the Azure app service which by default runs Gunicorn as the web server. The trick is to pass startup commands to by-pass this but I am not ale to figure it out. I was using the Gubicorn -k tornado and ran fine until now. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/tutorial-deploy-app-service-on-linux-04